# Squeeze a table column to it's minimum possible width

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, css-tables

Throughout my website, I have many `<table>`s in which there is a specific column we want to have squeezed to it's minimum possible space (without having it's text wrapped). Other sibling cells share the rest of the space automatically.

I'm using the following trick and it works in all browsers except IE7-. (At this time I actually only care about IE7)

```
table {width:100%;}
table td.min-col {white-space:nowrap; width:1px; }
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/vm8gc/23/

If you try this in IE7 you will notice it acts differently (not expected behavious). -- see screen capture below.

Can anyone think of a fix for IE7 to achieve this?

---

#### Attachments:

All other browsers:

[image]

IE7:

[image]

Comment: It may worth inspecting Google Spreadsheets. They've this Excel like feature for double-clicking the column border to make a best fit column resizing. The function called here may be useful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CSS 2 Version

For some reason Internet Explorer seems to ignore `white-space` on TDs. Best way around the problem is to use a span inside the TD.

```
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap;">This should not wrap</span></td>
```

As usual IE doing it's own thing ;)

For info on `white-space` support, see here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html

### PRE Version

An alternative which would have better support with older browsers would be to do the following:

```
<td><pre>This will not wrap</pre></td>
```

And then have your pre element set-up to either be styled in the same way as your normal text or enable it to inherit style from it's parents *(inheriting probably has less support that just specifiying the style)*:

```
td pre { font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit; color: inherit; ... }
```

Comment: It's sad that I have to do this everywhere, but your answer seems to be the only option. Thanks

Comment: @valipour - yep, that's the problem with having to support so many different interpreters of the same languages - the never-ending curse of the webdev :) You could always implement a javascript solution that would just fix Internet Explorer... meaning you can keep your markup nice for good browsers?

Comment: no, I think that would cause other issues. Adding the wrapper solves the problem perfectly and, in fact, is not dirty at all. but using js will make the maintenance of work horribly difficult.