# Increase width of a td so that the contents is on a single line

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
+----------------------+-------------------+
| This text is on the  | This text is on   |
| first column         | the second column |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| This text is on the first column | This text is on the second column |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

My table is longer than the screen and has many many lines, but this is the functionality I want from it. Is there a CSS property that can make this happen without truncating the text? If not could somebody point me to a javascript example on how to do this?

Comment: <td style="white-space: nowrap">

Comment: The `no-wrap` should work: http://jsfiddle.net/RpSZt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need wider browser support than `white-space: nowrap` you can use a pre tag. The css solution is nicer though so only use `pre` if you really have to:

```
<tr>
  <td><pre>This is my non wrapping text</pre></td>
  <td><pre>Some more non wrapping text</pre></td>
</tr>
```

Obviously this will only work for simple html in your table cells, plus `pre` generally comes with it's own default styling which you can get around with the following in CSS:

```
td pre {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  /* ... and so on */
}
```

Using `inherit` can be slightly less supported, so if you can it is best to actually define the style you want directly.

Comment: Why would the no-wrap property not work in some cases? http://jsfiddle.net/RpSZt/

Comment: @David This is coming from older knowledge - the last time I used this myself was probably well over 3 years ago. However there was a recent post here that led me to believe that there are still issues with browser support for `no-wrap` *(esp. with table cells)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212098/squeeze-a-table-column-to-its-minimum-possible-width/12212146#comment16361350_12212146 -- personally I would opt for the css version unless I have specific proof that it's not working for my target audience. We really should stop supporting archaic useragents...

Comment: @David np :) - as usual IE causing issues and detracting from the nice way of doing things.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space) property:

```
td { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td nowrap>Look ma</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```